# Why is $(T_1T_4-T_2T_3,T_1+T_4)\subseteq k[T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4]$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I want to show that $(T_1T_4-T_2T_3,T_1+T_4)\subseteq k[T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4]$ is a prime ideal, where $k$ is a field.

For this, I thought of $$k[T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4]/(T_1T_4-T_2T_3,T_1+T_4)\cong k[T_1,T_2,T_3]/(T_1^2+T_2T_3)$$ via $T_4\mapsto -T_1$, and the latter is an integral domain because $T_1^2+T_2T_3\subseteq (k[T_2,T_3])[T_1]$ is prime, since it is of degree $2$ in $T_1$ and has no roots in $k[T_2,T_3]$. My question is whether this is correct, or where the mistakes are; I don't feel very confident about these arguments in general and thought a quick verification could help me. Thanks!

Comment: this looks mostly good to me. The one thing I want to point out is that it is important that $T_1^2 +T_2 T_3$ is a _monic_ polynomial in $T_1$. For example, $(T_2 T_1 + 1)(T_3 T_1 +1) = (T_2 T_3)T_1^2 + (T_2 + T_3)T_1 + 1$ is a polynomial of degree 2 in $T_1$ with no roots in $k[T_2,T_3]$, but it still factors.

Comment: @BrianShin thank you! A good point that I should be aware of - it's because the coefficient ring is not a field that causes this, right?

Comment: that's exactly right